# Como colocar texto de uma textbox para outra

Tags: vba, textbox

Boa noite, poderiam me dar uma ajuda por gentileza?

Estou criando um projeto VBA no qual tenho um formulário que tem várias Textbox.
Tenho a Textbox1 como específica, na qual lançarei os valores, e toda vez que eu lançar um valor nela e saisse pelo Evento Exit, gostaria que passase para a Textbox2, e quando lançasse outro valor, o valor da Textbox2 fosse para a Textbox3, e o da Textbox1 fosse para a Textbox2.
Tipo uma catalogação.
Fico grato pela ajuda.